# logistic regression classifier by keras

Tags: python, keras, logistic-regression

I am trying to write a logistic regression model by keras.But I find out some problems:

The data I use is from Coursera Machine learning course(taught by Andrew NG) ex2.

and my code is below:

```
def model():
input_layer = Input(shape=(2,))
dense1 = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid',kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(seed=42),bias_initializer='zeros')(input_layer)
model = Model(input_layer,dense1)

return model
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,optimizer=Adam(),metrics=['accuracy']) 
model.fit(x=X,y=y,batch_size=10,epochs=10,verbose=1)
```

Here is the result I get:
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 120us/step - loss: 0.6335 - acc: 0.6000
Epoch 10/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 130us/step - loss: 0.6326 - acc: 0.6000

But if I use matlab `fminunc` function to find the result, I get:
Train Accuracy: 89.000000

Why the result can be different?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try optimising the batch size and epochs?

Comment: Have you normalized the input data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you have normalized the input data. Try normalizing it like this:

```
X = X.astype('float32')
X_mean = X.mean(axis=0)
X -= X_mean
X_std = X.std(axis=0)
X /= X_std + 1e-8
```

Further, increasing the learning rate might also help in this case as well: `optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-2)`, it helps the training to converge to a solution in fewer epochs.

Comment: I tried use increase the learning rate and I got the right result!. Thanks a lot